# Django query users that like each other

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, orm

I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class Matches(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am trying to write a query using django's ORM, but am stuck. Given a user (let's say user_1), I want to return all rows where user_1 has voted True on another user (let's say user_2) AND user_2 has voted True on user_1.

I'm thinking I might need to use Django's Q [function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) but not sure. Here is what I've got:

```
class User:
    def calculate_matches(self):    
        return Matches.objects.filter(Q(voter=self, vote=True) & Q(user=self, vote=True))
```

Comment: As I have understood, I think you are trying to query in two parts: **First fetch all the records where a voted has voted True**, then find all the users where the voter has voted true. **Then Display the record if the user(voted by the voter) also has voted for the user(voter).** Is it true? If yes then you may first fetch the users who the voter has voted true. Then for each user voted true by voter check the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

Consider User with ID `1` voted to User with ID `2` voted and vice versa.
Then relevant sql is

```
SELECT "users_matches"."id", "users_matches"."user_id", "users_matches"."voter_id", "users_matches"."vote" FROM "users_matches" WHERE ("users_matches"."vote" = True AND "users_matches"."voter_id" = 1 AND "users_matches"."user_id" = 2 AND "users_matches"."vote" = True)
```

And Django ORM you tried looks ok.

```
Matches.objects.filter(Q(voter=1, vote=True) & Q(user=2, vote=True))
```

Please include more information if you don't get exact output, mention which output you expect with sample output.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
class User:
    def calculate_matches(self):    
        return Matches.objects.filter(Q(voter=self) | Q(user=self),  vote=True)
```

Means, it will return all the matches where voter is user himself/herself or he is the user when some else voted him.